# Suggestion on Papers to Read on Classifier Selection

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I'm looking for some papers to read to get started understanding *classifier selection* method in a computer security system.

I wanted to develop a Multiple Classifier System based on a pool of classifier (heterogenous classifiers). The idea is like the system will select the most competent algorithm for a particular dataset using the classifier selection method.

Could you suggest me some papers in computer security (like intrusion detection for example) or other areas that employ the method?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the activity currently going on around ['automated machine learning'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_machine_learning) / ['AutoML'](https://www.automl.org/) goes into that direction, although it is not limited to the selection of a classification model.

While I won't provide a literature review on the topic here, I think having a look at what papers cite AutoML and similar projects might give you the results you are looking for.